# Why does this D3 closure not return the correct attribute

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have the following code, which is a part of a file which creates a simple scatter chart in D3. This should be very basic, as I am just learning the library. Below I have function `breathAnimate` which should adjust the circle's radius either up or down 5 pixels. As you can see in the code, it looks for a `smaller` attribute on the element. If that element is there (and has a value of 1), the radius of the circle is decreased by 5.

The `smaller` attribute is then added so that the next time through the loop, the other side of the if/else conditional will run. The else part of the conditional increases the radius by 5 and removes the `smaller` attribute.

The function then calls itself so the animation is continuously run. The idea is for the radius of the circle to animate up and down by 5 pixels continuously.

### The Problem

Instead of changing the `t` and/or the `r` variable to reference the current circle element running through the loop, something in the function is referencing the same element every time. So instead of the circles getting larger and smaller, they just keep larger and larger.

### The Code

```
// define the animation
var breathAnimate = function(d){
    var t = d3.select(this);
    var r = t.attr('r');

    t.transition()
      .attr('r',function(){
        if( d3.select(this).attr('smaller') == null) {
            t.attr('smaller','1');
            return r + 5;
        } else {
            t.attr('smaller',null);
            return r - 5;
        }
      })
      .each('end',breathAnimate)
    ;
}

// start things off
d3.selectAll('circle')
    .transition()
    .attr('r', function(d){return d})
    .each('end',breathAnimate)
;
```

I'm hoping someone with more experience at D3 (I've been using it for about 2 days) will be able to easily point out where I've done something wrong. I'm guessing this is not some arcane bug, but instead something simple I've overlooked out of inexperience.

Comment: Your code works for me: http://plnkr.co/edit/6AKqXSVwcSzJmWdUobwf?p=preview

Comment: Yes, but only for a single data point as @mgraham points out in his answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the plunker code and it worked for 1 circle, but then did the ever expanding thing for 2 when I made it a data bound example -->

http://plnkr.co/edit/ep8MXrPF6Bh3xMMhXBJk?p=preview

Poking about, it's because .attr("r") is getting returned as a string (the previous plunker returned undefined) and "5" is just getting added to the end of the previous value. Doing `var r = +t.attr('r');` fixes it

Comment: Thank you, you really solved the problem. For the record, I did `var r = parseInt( t.attr('r') , 10 );` just to be more explicit about what I'm actually doing. Thanks!